# PostgreSQL: How to use constraints in base types of a composite types

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I created a PostgreSQL composite data type for `person_name` consisting of `prefix`, `first`, `middle`, `last`, `suffix`, and `title` parts. 
However, I want `last` to be `NOT NULL` which `CREATE TYPE` does not support.

I found one way around this - using domain with type restriction.
So following works:

```
CREATE DOMAIN text_required AS text NOT NULL;

CREATE TYPE person_name AS (
  prefix text,
  first  text_required,
  middle text,
  last   text,
  suffix text,
  title  text     
);
```

Some questions:

1. Is the above the recommended way to achieve composite data types with column restrictions or is there a better way?
2. Would I be better off using `jsonb` column instead of composite data type for this purpose? If so, how would I constrain it (validate that it is an object, that the keys are present, and that key `last` is not null)

Comment: I have used domains in exactly this way, and it works fine.